# We need to have certain javascript files loaded at the very beginning

Tags: meteor

We are using trackjs.com code to  help us detect javascript errors. We want the trackjs code to report all errors in any javascript code. This requires that the trackjs code be loaded first.

I know it goes against the general meteor loading order, however we don't want any javascript issues hidden, no matter where the errors are.

We tried including the trackjs.com code included in the `compatibility` folder and hardcoded in a `<head>` block. Both of these approaches resulted in the code being loaded last.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [official documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#structuringyourapp):

- Files in subdirectories are loaded before files in parent directories, so that files in the deepest subdirectory are loaded first, and files in the root directory are loaded last.
- Within a directory, files are loaded in alphabetical order by filename.
- After sorting as described above, all files under directories named `lib` are moved before everything else (preserving their order).
- Finally, all files that match `main.*` are moved after everything else (preserving their order).

So you should be placing them in the `lib` directory. If you place it in `server/lib` it is going to be available to the server, or in `client/lib` the client only. But if you place it in a common `lib` folder, then it is going to be available to both the client and the server.

That being said, it is usually a better idea to place such code into its own package. Packages have better loading order management as described in the [relevant section](http://docs.meteor.com/#writingpackages) of the docs.

Finally, you might also want to look at http://observatoryjs.com/ which targets to achieve a similar solution as trackjs and it has native meteor packages you can search and add from http://atmosphere.meteor.com

UPDATE:

These solutions place trackjs after meteor's native code and before yours and any other 3rd party's.

To be able to truly inject trackjs before everything else, there may be a few ways:

https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-fast-render/blob/master/lib/server/inject.js#L52 is how fast-render package alters the contents of head to inject arbitrary scripts. You can inject trackjs at the very beginning using this technique.

You can directly hack https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/webapp/webapp_server.js how meteor serves the app. This would again be client side only and prone to meteor update conflicts.

Comment: Unfortunately, your suggestion will not work. The meteor code is still loaded first. As specified in the question: we want trackjs to be able to report *any* error, not just the errors after some arbitrary loading point. Additionally, observatory is loaded in the middle of the package loading.

Comment: @Pat you're right, I was too quick to jump to conclusions. I updated the answer with two possible ways. Let me know if they work for you. Also, if you need to do the same on the server side (and if trackjs would be able to make arbitrary http calls from your server) I'll see if I can help you there as well.

Comment: thanks for the update for 2 reasons. #1; didn't know about FastRender; #2 - the basic idea of hooking the http initial request handling, while possibly problematic is certainly better than the alternative of hacking meteor.